# Azure Web Application Gate (w/WAF) public IP opening/redirecting Azure App Services on port 80 instead of actual Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I have a App Gateway WAF V2 configured for both public and private IP for my Azure Web Application (this uses Azure AD Authentication to access also), when I try to access the Web App through the App Gateway Public IP Address it will open on the page "webapp.azurewebsites.net:80" which leads to the following error:

[image]

The expected behaviors is that the "webapp.azurewebsites.net" (without the port 80 at the end) will be loaded and the web app displayed, if I remove the :80 from the end of the URL it loads as expected.

These are my configurations below for the Application Gateway (My Backend Setting and Backend Pool both have the same name btw)
Listeners:

Public

[image: User's image]

Private

[image]

Rules:
Public
[image]

[image]

Private
[image]

[image]

Backend Pool:
[image]

Backend Settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to use Application gateway public Ip address to redirect app service when I run application gateway IP with `port 80` *20.x.x.70:80* it redirect your app service like [this](https://i.imgur.com/v1mrwZr.png)

Comment: How would i go about doing this? I am new to App Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the same step and got the same error :

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> webappXXX.azurewebsites.net  sent an invalid response.
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

To resolve this issue, check the below workaround:

***In your App service -> configuration -> General setting.***

[image]

By default, your app service would have HTTPS only change to `off` like below:

[image]

When HTTPS only is enabled, all HTTP traffic is redirected to HTTPS if you turn off the HTTPS only it will redirect successfully.

**Note**: Once you turn off, ***Restart*** the app service and make sure to ***clear cache*** on 24hr.

Now when I hit the application gateway public Ip it redirects successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to change App service you can use port `443` in    Http setting and use well known certificate as `yes`  check the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=defaultdomain,azure-portal#edit-http-settings-for-app-service)

Comment: This seems to have done the trick using no HTTPS!
I tried again using HTTPS with an uncached browser with "use well known certificate" and got this error instead I get a 502 Bad Gateway error?
But I do have it working with http which is great for the time being